# Check if MD5 value exists in an index file

Tags: python, md5, scanning

I am trying to figure out a way to verifying if my code can cross-verify the existence of a url string's md5 conversion value in an index file and if yes skip the scan.

**Below is my code**

The url formed is **converted** to md5 string and then stored in a idx file once scan completes, the goal is future scans should not pickup the same url. The issue I see is `if str(md5url) in line` is not getting executed, probably because am not using '\n' as a suffix while adding the hash to the file. But I tried that its still not working.

Any ideas?

```
def computeMD5hash(string_for_hash):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(string_for_hash.encode('utf-8'))
    return m.hexdigest()


def writefilehash(formation_URL):
    fn="urlindex.idx"
    try:
        afile = open(fn, 'a')
        afile.write(computeMD5hash(formation_URL))
        afile.close()
    except IOError:
        print("Error writing to the index file")

fn="urlindex.idx"
try:
    afile = open(fn, 'r')
except IOError:
    afile = open(fn, 'w')

for f in files:
    formation=repouri + "/" + f
    #print(computeMD5hash(formation))
    md5url=computeMD5hash(formation)
    hashlist = afile.readlines()
    for line in hashlist:
        if str(md5url) in line:
            print ("Skipping " + formation + " because its already scanned and indexed as  " + line)
        else:
            if downloadengine(formation):
                print ("Download completed " + formation)
                print ("Starting to write to database..")
                #writetodatabase()
                print ("Writing hash value ..")
                writefilehash(formation)

print("Closing..")
afile.close()
```

Comment: You are writing all hashes on one long line into the file. The `md5url in line` check will still succeed however, newlines do not play a role there, `in` tests for *containment*, not equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing *in a loop*. For every line that doesn't match, you download:

```
line1
    if hash in line:
        print something
    else
        download
line2
    if hash in line:
        print something
    else
        download
line3
    if hash in line:
        print something
    else
        download
```

If the hash is in line 1, then you still download, because the hash is not in line 2 or line 3. You should not decide to download **until you tested all lines**.

The best way to do this is to read all the hashes in one go, into a set object (because testing for containment against a set is faster). Remove the line separators:

```
try:
    with open(fn) as hashfile:
        hashes = {line.strip() for line in hashfile}
except IOError:
    # no file yet, just use an empty set
    hashes = set()
```

then when testing new hashes use:

```
urlhash = computeMD5hash(formation)
if urlhash not in hashes:
    # not seen before, download
    # record the hash
    hashes.add(urlhash)
    with open(fn, 'a') as hashfile:
        hashfile.write(urlhash + '\n')
```